# App-engine: cannot import name storage python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

I am trying to create a little server in Google Cloud Platform that receives an image and put it in Storage.

But when server is deploying always writes in logs the same error:

> ImportError: cannot import name storage
>   at  (/base/data/home/apps/my_environment/my_server:000000000000000.000000000000000000/main.py:15)
>   at LoadObject (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/8882c914eb6132e9_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:85)
>   at _LoadHandler (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/8882c914eb6132e9_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:299)
>   at Handle (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/8882c914eb6132e9_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:240)

My function is like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage

...

def post_icon(request):
    file = request.files['file']
    package = request.form['package']
    if file and _allowed_file(file.filename):
        gcs = storage.Client()
        bucket = gcs.get_bucket(CLOUD_STORAGE_APP_ICONS_SEGMENT)
        blob = bucket.blob(file.filename)
        blob.upload_from_string(
        file.read(),
        content_type=file.content_type
        )
        return {'code': 200 , 'message': blob.public_url }

    else:
        return {'code': 400 }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google.cloud import storage: cannot import storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840511/google-cloud-import-storage-cannot-import-storage)

Comment: Is your code running on App Engine Standard or Flexible environment?

Comment: Have you followed the steps explained in the [google.cloud import storage: cannot import storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840511/google-cloud-import-storage-cannot-import-storage) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for me:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.http

storage = googleapiclient.discovery.build('storage', 'v1')

def post_icon(request):
    file = request.files['file']
    package = request.form['package']
    app = request.form['app']
    if file and _allowed_file(file.filename) and not _have_app_icon(package):
        body = {
            'name': file.filename,
        }
        req = storage.objects().insert(
            bucket=CLOUD_STORAGE_APP_ICONS_SEGMENT, body=body,
            media_body=googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseUpload(
                 file.stream, 'image/jpeg'))
        resp = req.execute()
```

Now I can put images at Storage in GCP. Thanks for comment and see my question!